# Is a "knot knot" or "double knot" a thing in knot theory?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, terminology

I apologize in advance for my rudimentary knowledge of knot theory, but I've been trying to find out about the significance (if any) of taking a knot (particularly a torus knot), cutting it, and forming another knot using it.  Some examples:

**trefoil knot of a trefoil knot**

[image]

**and another "double trefoil" knot**

[image]

Is there a generally accepted name for this?  Is the resulting knot prime? Are there any other generalizations one can make about these?

Thank you for any information you have on this.

Comment: Knot knot is kyes.

Comment: I should have seen that coming.

Comment: Well, only if you assume the law of excluded kmiddle. In intuitionistic knot theory, knot knot can be slightly weaker than a kyes (so I wouldn't use it to secure a repel line, for example).

Comment: I think you're looking for 'satellite knots'.

Comment: Besides satellite knots suggested by HJRW you probably want to look up [framed knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_%28mathematics%29#Framed_knot) as well. You can consider framing as the knots being made of orientable ribbon rather than a line. Framed knots are central to some topology topics, such as Kirby Calculus.

Comment: All the "doubling" type operations you are considering results in prime knots (or links, if you allow yourself to construct objects with more than one component).

Comment: I have seen "not knot"

Comment: Makes me wonder if Asaf was born with family name Aragila.  (That would explain much.)  Gerhard "Going Out On A Klimb"  Paseman, 2016.01.18

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [satellite knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot) (or link) is more general that your construction.  To make a satellite knot, you take a knot in a solid torus (not in a ball within the solid torus), and embed the solid torus so that it is knotted.

A [doubled knot](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubledKnot.html) (or Whitehead double of a knot) is special type of satellite knot that is different from yours.

Your knots are [cablings](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CableKnot.html) of a knot, where the knot in the solid torus is a torus knot following a curve on the boundary. The slope is usually parametrized $(p,q)$ and yours are $(2,n)$ cablings for some $n$. Nontrivial cablings are prime (see Burde and Zieschang, *Knots*, p. 93) so your knots are prime.

---

Thanks to Ryan Budney for pointing out that my initial definition of satellite know was more restricted than a more common one.

Comment: All satellite knots are prime.... **except** for the ones that are not!   :)  Connect-sums are satellite knots, and they are not prime.

Comment: @Ryan Budney: Yes, that's one definition, but I don't like that one. I said that the meridianal disk has to intersect the knot at least twice, which I think rules out connected sums and gives a $\pi_1$-injective torus.

Comment: You need to say it a bit more strongly than how you did it, Douglas, since you could take a messy embedding of the knot into the torus which is still isotopic to one that meets some disk in one or zero points.

Comment: Oh, okay.  But readers should be aware that your defnition is a special case of the ones you see in the original articles (Schubert) as well as most textbooks and research articles that use the notion.

Comment: @JimConant: By meridianal disk, I meant topological meridianal disk.